# Pentaho JNDI source name as parameter (Multi-Tennant)

Tags: pentaho

I have googled this for the last half an hour, and found hits for pentaho parameters etc but nothing that appears to ask or answer this question.

I have a set of reports that are the same for each customer, but need to connect to different databases depending upon the customer who is running the report.

So my idea is to pass the JNDI data source name to the report at runtime as a parameter, so that the customer will connect to the correct database.

Is this possible, or is there a better way of managing a common set of reports that are used by different customers running on different databases but in the same single instance of the pentaho engine ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I have found a better solution using the little documented multi-tennant feature.

1) Stop Pentaho

2) Modify ( pentaho-solutions/system/pentahoObjects.spring.xml )

```
<!-- Original Code
 <bean id="IDBDatasourceService" class="org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.connection.datasource.dbcp.DynamicallyPooledOrJndiDatasourceService" scope="singleton">
   <property name="pooledDatasourceService" ref="pooledOrJndiDatasourceService" />
   <property name="nonPooledDatasourceService" ref="nonPooledOrJndiDatasourceService" />
 </bean>
 -->

 <!--Begin Tenant -->
   <bean id="IDBDatasourceService" class="org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.connection.datasource.dbcp.tenantaware.TenantAwareLoginParsingDatasourceService"
   scope="singleton">
     <property name="requireTenantId" value="false" />
     <property name="datasourceNameFormat" value="{1}-{0}" />
     <property name="tenantSeparator" value="@" />
     <property name="tenantOnLeft" value="false" />
   </bean>
 <!-- End Tenant -->
```

3) Add Suffix to Data Sources ( biserver-ce/tomcat/webapps/pentaho/META-INF/context.xml )

```
<Resource
  name="jdbc/MYDBSRC-xxx"
  auth="Container"
  type="javax.sql.DataSource"
  factory="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory"
  maxActive="20"
  maxIdle="5"
  maxWait="10000"
  username="XXXX"
  password="XXXX"
  driverClassName="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"
  url="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.168.42.0:1433;DatabaseName=SOMEDB"
/>

<Resource
  name="jdbc/MYDBSRC-aaa"
  auth="Container"
  type="javax.sql.DataSource"
  factory="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory"
  maxActive="20"
  maxIdle="5"
  maxWait="10000"
  username="XXXX"
  password="XXXX"
  driverClassName="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"
  url="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.168.42.0:1433;DatabaseName=AOTHERDB"
/>
```

4) Delete /tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/pentaho.xml

5) Restart Pentaho, create a user someone@xxx etc etc

6) Create a report using the JNDI Name "MYDBSRC"

7) Login as someone@xxx and you will get a different report / datasource than either logging in as user, or user@aaa

**Tadah !!**