# How implement this feature in Pentaho 8.0 CE?

Tags: pentaho, multi-tenant

In the documentation https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/8.0/Developer_Center/Multi-Tenancy has the advertaisement: "*Audience: This article is designed for architects and developers who are familiar with multi-tenancy and ready to consider applying their business requirements to parts of their Pentaho system.*", but i'm not developers familiar with multi-tenancy.

Can be more clear about the steps to implement that? Tanks

Comment: Not sure what is your question.. you don't know what is multi tenancy ? You want to know how to implement Multi-tenancy with a Pentaho Server(this is natural) ?

Comment: Hello Cristian. 
I now what is multi-tenancy. 
I try to implement the sharing solution. I the pentahoObjects.spring.xml in the bean IDBDatasourceService change the class to org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.connection.datasource.dbcp.tenantaware.TenantAwareSessionVariableDatasourceService.
The problem is how the JNDI in the cda file add the tenant_ID.

Comment: Hi. 
I use this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32877430/pentaho-jndi-source-name-as-parameter-multi-tennant?rq=1 and works for me.
The only change is in the property "tenantSeparator", because LDAP don't accept @. Tanks

Comment: I never used the report tools myself, but in Data-Integration (kettle) what i do to achieve that is create a 'variable' connection, whatever SQL statement used, connects with this 'variable connection', and the execution has 2 parameters. which are used in this connection, host and database name. I would like to believe there is a similar functionality in the reports, where you can pass parameters in run time.